# node.js - How to set an encoding in a dgram socket

Tags: node.js, udp

Is there a way to set the encoding for a dgram UDP socket the same as setting the encoding in a TCP/IP net socket?
 I'm looking for the equivalent of the method socket.SetEncoding in the net.Socket class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`socket.setEncoding([encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setencoding_encoding)

> Set the encoding for the socket as a Readable Stream. See stream.setEncoding() for more information.

UDP sockets do not implement the `Readable Stream` interface, hence it does not apply to them.

If you need to convert the binary message ([`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer)) you have recieved via your UDP socket to a String in a specific encoding,
just use `buf.toString([encoding[, start[, end]]])` method instead.